# How do I exclude a base class using fluent mappings in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, schema, nhibernate-mapping

I have an abstract base class, `Entity`, that all my POCOs derive from:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping file:

```
public class EntityMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Entity
{
    public EntityMap
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

This way, I don't have to write `Id(x => x.Id)` in every mapping file by using this:

```
public class Something : EntityMap<T>
{
    blahblah
}
```

I'm auto-generating my database schema, and everything looks fine, except that the Entity base class is added as a table. Using fluent mappings, how do I configure it so that the Entity class is excluded from the database schema?

Comment: Whoops, found my answer. The Entity table was leftover from a previous database schema generation. Apparently NHibernate only generates NEW tables (and drops old ones if they have the same name in order to replace them with the new one), but does not remove any already-existing tables that don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the ignore list of auto mapper:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>()
  .IgnoreBase(typeof(Entity));
```